# Can you synthesize the RISC-V rocket chip test harness module?

Tags: rocket-chip

After I setup the rocket-chip, it generated example top level Verilog.  Can I synthesize the `testharness.v` module?  I manually import the code into `vivado`, but got **syntax error** in `SimDTM.v`

> `(import "DPI-C" function int debug_tick)`

- vivado doesn't know what to do with DPI-C
- Did I miss some package?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but you can't synthesize the testharness. It's used for testing in simulation only. DPI is a simulation-only construct.